# Use of a constant in generating a random number

Tags: java

I am new in Java and while trying to understand the code below, I cannot figure out the purpose of the constant. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
    int a = (int)((Double)array.get(i)).doubleValue();
    Random r = new Random(a*constant);
    Q += r.nextDouble() * 2 + 1;
```

Comment: It is seeding the PRNG with some value. See: [`Random(long seed)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#Random-long-).

Comment: @JohnnyMopp `a` (without multiplying with the constant) would also be seeding the `Random`